# Jenkins does not find GitHub repositories owned by another user

Tags: jenkins, github

I'm trying to get a new Jenkins on-premises install (Ubuntu server, Jenkins, and plugins updated to latest versions as of 2020-05-18) to access private GitHub repositories owned by another user, but the *Scan Organization Log* says "0 repositories were processed". Jenkins correctly found and processed private repositories owned by my user.

I verified my user has access to those repositories by executing an HTTP GET to *https://api.github.com/user/repos* using the exact same credentials that I'm using with Jenkins. The response contains the repository that I want to use with Jenkins (screenshot below).

When I set "Owner" in Jenkins to my username, Jenkins correctly finds all repositories under my user:
[Screenshot of config section of UI with Scan Org Log for my user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0eX8.png)

However, when I set the "Owner" to another username, Jenkins does not find any repositories:
[Screenshot of config section of UI with Scan Org Log for another user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Yvv.png)

An API call to *https://api.github.com/user/repos* using the same credentials as Jenkins shows I have access to that repo (plus, I can read from/write to that repo using GitHub Desktop): [Screenshot of result of API call to */user/repos*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FALhQ.png)

If I use the username/access token of the private repo owner, Jenkins sees them fine, but I don't want to have multiple different sets of credentials in Jenkins, especially for repo owners. Ideally, I'd just have a single, limited-access Jenkins-specific account, but I think the first step is to try getting this to work with a user I know has the correct access.

The same behaviour happens whether or not a 'Jenkinsfile' file is present (Jenkins needs to know that a repo exists before it can even check for any files, so I'm guessing that's not relevant, yet).

Any idea how to get this to work?

Thanks!